# jquery draggable not showing up for the div outside the viewport

Tags: jquery

I have the draggable li to be dragged to the multiple divs, The div outside the viewport is not being recognised by the draggable thing. 
Sample code is

```
$("li[elName=fieldEl]").draggable(
{
    connectToSortable       :   $("#fieldsList,#subformdiv")
    containment             :   $('#build-main'),   
    appendTo                :   $("#formBuilderSlide"), 
    helper                  :   "clone",
    zIndex                  :   104,
    start : function(){},
    drag  : function(){},
    revert : function{}
});
```

`#fieldslist` div is being recognized but the `#subformdiv` is present outside the viewport. when scrolling to that part to drag and drop the 'li', the draggable is not recognizing it.

Subform div is inside fieldslist div and these two divs are inside build-main.

How to overcome this issue?

Comment: Provide a working example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. However as per my understanding the issue is the draggable is not recognizing outside the `#fieldset` div.

**The probable reason is `#subformdiv` is outside of the `#build-main` div. In the given code you have set the dragging bounds to `#build-main` div and any div outside of that will not be recognized.**

Try to put `#subformdiv` within the `#build-main` div.

I have created a sample one out of my imagination. Might be useful to get an idea.

- There `#out` is an outer div (with blue coloured) to `#build-main` div and draggable is not working in that div. But all the other divs are within the `#build-main` and draggable is working for them.

```js
$(function() {
          $("li[elName=fieldEl]").draggable({
            connectToSortable: $("#fieldsList,#subformdiv"),
            containment: $('#build-main'),
            appendTo: $("#formBuilderSlide"),
            helper: "clone",
            zIndex: 104,
            start: function() {},
            drag: function() {},
            revert: function() {}

          });
        });
```

```css
#fieldslist {
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: #eee;
}
#subformdiv {
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: yellow;
}
#formBuilderSlide {
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: green;
}
#build-main {
  padding: 0.5em;
}
#out {
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="out">

</div>
<div id="build-main">
  <div id="fieldslist" class="ui-widget-content">
    <ul>
      <li elName="fieldEl">
        A
      </li>
      <li elName="fieldEl">
        B
      </li>
      <li elName="fieldEl">
        C
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="subformdiv">

  </div>
  <div id="formBuilderSlide">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added some line check above. Subform div is inside fieldslist div. Both the div are inside build-main. There is no issue with fieldslist div bcoz it occupies whole portion and it will always be in the viewport. Subform div is being recognised when it is in the viewport, the issue is when subform div is somewhere else but not visible in the viewport when i drag the element and scroll down to that subform div, it  is not being recognised.